# Are js promise chains inside useEffect guaranteed to be completed before being garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, react-hooks

I'm looking for information about whether promises chains are guaranteed to be completed before being garbage collected if the reference is lost. I'm executing a call to my API within a React useEffect hook, but am not clear about what happens if one of the dependencies change and the useEffect hook is re-executed while the promise is still pending.

**A contrived example:**

```
const useApiFetch = (query, myVariable) => {
  const client = useClient();

  useEffect(()=>{
    client
      .query(query)
      .then(() => console.log('inside thenable'))
      .catch(() => console.log('inside catch');
  },[variable, client]);
}
```

**Questions:**

- What happens if `myVariable` changes and `useEffect` is re-executed while the promise is pending? Will the promise complete before being garbage collected?
- What about if the component that is consuming this hook is re-rendered or removed from the virtual DOM?
- If I don't have a cleanup function, is there any chance of a memory leak?

Comment: "*Will the promise complete before being garbage collected?*" - yes. Always. The promise (and its attaches fulfillment/rejection handlers) are what *keeps* the closed-over variables (none in your example) from being garbage-collected. And what keeps the promise alive is the stuff that you're doing in `client.query`.

Comment: @Bergi thank you. client.query returns a promise, so I was assuming something needed to keep reference to that object if I’m not awaiting it. Is it fair to say that as long as the client is in scope, the promise will be too?

Comment: No. It's whatever the method is doing, e.g. making an api request. Then the open HTTP request is holding on the callback that will fulfill the promise, and thereby on the promise and its handlers. If the method would return a promise and never resolve it, it would just get garbage-collected.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be the perfect one but from my usage with react and functional components i will try to answer these.

When your dependencies for the hook changes, the function inside is re invoked. That means in your case a second api call. What this in turn results in may depend on api response time, client device, internet speed and way you handle these.

For example, if you are rendering something in the promise success for example a Text. What happens is once you UI renders the first data that it gets, like if you are setting state or something. Aa soon as the next api call resolves the UI again re-renders to reflect that change.

taking your example code. If you change the dependency "variable" three times, you get three "inside thenable" if promise resolves or else the catch console.log.

***Note:*** If for any reason you api process takes some time for example a large query, then you may not be able to tell which api call will get resolved first. I had this issue when i implemented a text based onChange search using api. A good solution will be to debounce your api calls to limit no of calls and also to cancel unwanted calls.

If you have setStates that is tied to your promise resolution/rejection and you haven't properly handled the unmount condition. React will show you a warning stating the same. Something that means "You have a state change happening in an unmounted component/screen". This can lead to memory leaks if left unchecked.

***Hope you get some point out of this. I am not a pro at this, these are somethings that i found while working with React.***

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The actual function I've got being invoked in my `then` function takes action on a global variable and emits an event, which other hooks subscribe to. Beyond that, the API call is debounced and the client has some deduping logic built in. So I don't think it's a major problem there. But I am very curious about the long-running query example. The Promise lives inside the useEffect closure. I think this may be a question about how long are useEffect closures kept in scope...if they're discarded, the Promise becomes a dangling reference + gets picked up by GC.

Comment: The useEffect hooks and other hooks if the are inside child components gets discarded after the component gets unmounted. But the last api call that was triggered before the unmount will either resolve/reject. So if you are scoping the resolution to a global variable or to redux somehow there will be final action. But if this hook is in a higher order component like App.js then the hook will remain in effect as long as app is running.

If you need to kill the long running query so that it doesn't cause any ripple effects even after the component gets GC, you will have to cancel the api call.